# Removing string characters from multiple column

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table like this:

```
YSQ     YSQR     ys     Y
 12     12       55     11
 abc    22       qrs     2
 #      def      @       aaa
```

I need to remove all String characters and special characters from all columns in a single hive query which would look like this:

```
YSQ   YSQR     ys     Y
12    12       55     11
11    22       33     2
2     22       11     33
```

I have tried a query but it is not working as expected:

```
select YSQ,YSQR,YS,Y from Sales_table2 where (YSRQTYPCS not rlike '[^0-9.-]') or YTTLSVAL not rlike '[^0-9.-]' or YSRTLSVAL not rlike '[^0-9.-]' or YSQTYPCS not rlike '[^0-9.-]'")
```

Comment: What is not working? Could you please post some error logs or the output?

Comment: There is no error, the field values are as it is there is no effect of the query on the table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For removing all String characters and special characters you have to used `REGEXP_REPLACE` function.

for remove the string characters

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(YSQ, '[a-zA-Z]+', '')
```

OR

You can also use the following to remove any non-numeric characters:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(YSQ, '[^0-9]', '') as YSQ from Sales_table2
```

Comment: For the first one :- REGEXP_REPLACE(YSQ, '[a-zA-Z]+', '')  how can i do this for multiple columns in single query?

Comment: no, you have to apply it on each column like this   `select REGEXP_REPLACE(YSQ, '[a-zA-Z]+', '') , REGEXP_REPLACE(YSQR, '[a-zA-Z]+', '') ,REGEXP_REPLACE(ys , '[a-zA-Z]+', '')  from Sales_table2`

Comment: Just one more thing what if i have to completely remove those records, the query you gave is replacing the records with empty records.

Comment: No actually i need to drop those records?

Comment: but practically its droping the values

Comment: when i use your query i was left with a table having void spaces in places where there where string values. I need to drop that entire row